# Arduino pin 13 dead - does that mean replacement board is dead?

Tags: arduino

I have purchased an Arduino Uno R3 and when I was working with my project, by mistake some wire went to the board and connected R3 pin with itself (connects pins of the LED). Then pin 13 LED fired and after that, all pins became dead. When I upload, RX and RT LEDs blink like usual, but all other pins don't work. I have uploaded a program with all pins set as output but none work.

Does that mean my board is dead? How do I check if my board is dead?

Comment: I think you have already determined that your board is dead. It is not uncommon that part of an MCU can be damaged by mistreating one of its pins whilst other parts still seem to function. It really sounds like you will have to replace your "uno r3" to get back to full functionality. Good luck and be more careful next time. Be happy that you were not using some expensive high end FPGA board when made the wiring mistake.

Comment: Some Arduinos use DIP package microcontrollers. If yours does then you can often find the correct part (probably an ATMEGA328P) on eBay for a lot less than you'll pay for a new (genuine) Arduino. Arduino chips have special bootloaders - be sure to buy a chip pre-programmed with the Arduino bootloader (otherwise you'll have to program it yourself, which requires another Arduino).

Comment: An example of this would be this listing on eBay: http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Atmega328P-PU-Arduino-Bootloader-16MHZ-Crystal-22pF-Capacitors-Atmega328p-/131675293038?var=&hash=item1ea875856e:m:m-HtOvcZkVKeHVChrjG_bwA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you already know.

To test pins, you can simply load in a program that sets all pins to outputs and then will toggle each pin high and low at a slow rate (like 1 second). You can then use either a multimeter to observe the voltage toggling between 0V and 5V, or you can do it visually by connecting an LED with an appropriate series resistor (1k is fine) to each pin one at a time. Just be sure you have the LED pointing in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you cannot upload anything to the Arduino is a good indicator that it is dead. Unless you have the SMD version of the UNO, you can replace the ATmega328 by itself and keep the rest of board. You will need to burn the boot loader first, as LeoR pointer out.

It possible however, to fry the ATmega16u2 microcontroller (black square behind USB connector and next to the metallic crystal oscillator) that enables the ATmega328 to be reprogrammed. Since the ATmega16u2 is a surface-mount component, you cannot replace it by itself and must replace the entire Arduino UNO. One way to fry it is to connect 12V to the DC jack and connect a jumper between VIN and 5V. This will fry both the ATmega16u2 and ATmega328.